# Asterisk dial call warning Purely numeric hostname

Tags: call, asterisk, out

I installed a FreePbx. But I have a problem. I want to call my own cell phone, but I can't.

I have an ip phone. I changed his type from pjsip to sip.

Extensions:102

extensions.conf:

```
[cocugunuzukarsilayin]
exten => myphonenumber,1,Answer()
exten => myphonenumber,n,Wait(1)
exten => myphonenumber,n,Playback(custom/sound2)
exten => myphonenumber,n,Wait(1)
exten => myphonenumber,n,Hangup()
```

test.call

```
Channel: SIP/102/myphonenumber
MaxRetries: 2
RetryTime: 30
WaitTime: 15
Context: cocugunuzukarsilayin
Extension: cocugunuzukarsilayin
Priority: 2
```

Error:

```
[2019-06-19 14:08:39] WARNING[8744]: chan_sip.c:6274 create_addr: Purely numeric hostname (102), and not a peer--rejecting!
[2019-06-19 14:08:39] NOTICE[8744]: pbx_spool.c:447 attempt_thread: Call failed to go through, reason (0) Call Failure (not BUSY, and not NO_ANSWER, maybe Circuit busy or down?)
[2019-06-19 14:08:39] WARNING[8744]: pbx_spool.c:350 safe_append: Unable to set utime on /var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/test.call: Operation not permitted
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message. Moreover, I could not place calls. My message log had the sequence below:

```
chan_sip.c: Purely numeric hostname (1001), and not a peer--rejecting!
app_dial.c: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
```

I finally found the solution, prompted by reading [here](https://apfelboymchen.net/gnu/notes/asterisk-pjsip.html). My problem was caused by a mismatch between technology types in *extensions.conf*. I was in the process of switching from *sip.conf* to *pjsip.conf*. But I failed to update my *extensions.conf* properly.

```
exten => 1001,1,Dial(SIP/1001,20,Ttm)
same  => n,Hangup
```

The fix was to modify as follows:

```
exten => 1001,1,Dial(PJSIP/1001,20,Ttm)
same  => n,Hangup
```

Once that **SIP** was changed to **PJSIP**, the error messages were eliminated and normal functionality was restored.

Answer (score 0):

Format of the channel is as follows:

```
Channel: <Technology/Channel_Type>/<Resource/Gateway>/<Extension/Number>
```

Please check the '102' mentioned is a valid gateway.